# Get Sheet By Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the following formula to work:

```
function setDataValid(range, sourceRange) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit() {
  var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

  if (aColumn == 2 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Local' ) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    setDataValid(range, sourceRange)
  }
}
```

When debugging onEdit() it shows that sourceRange in setDataValid(range, sourceRange) is null. As the range is in my sheet 'Local' I'm trying to change the getActiveSpreadsheet() to a get spreadsheet by name. Anyone who can help ?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use get sheet by name on the spreadsheet:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Local')
```

Answer (score 11):

Its very simple just get the sheet by name, the syntax is as follows as per the documentation.

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Expenses");
```

Comment: `getActive` and `getActiveSpreadsheet` are synonymous. Prefer the former as the latter is too similar to `getActiveSheet`, which does not return a `Spreadsheet` object.

Comment: I dont believe this is true any longer.  `getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(xxx)` returns an error currently.  `getActive().getSheetByName()` works.

Comment: Where exactly is getSheetByName documented? It's used in several places in the [Sheet Class doc page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) but never explicitly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the statement

```
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
```

This should be the one returning null. For the cause look at the [official documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String)).

```
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Local!TaxRates')
```

should get the range.

Comment: Thanks. But I need the getRangeByName value to depend on the value in the cell I have just edited

Comment: Use the parameter of the getRangeByName to include both your sheet name and the cell value, which has the named range name.  `var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Local!'+aCell.getValue())`

Comment: Still comes back like this
Argument cannot be null: range (line 2, file "Code")