# Google Sheets: Trigger puts in data on the wrong sheet

Tags: triggers, eventtrigger, google-sheets-macros

I have programmed a macro in Google Sheets that displays a table to show the history of certain data that changes every day. Every day the macro inserts a new line with a new date into the table. This is done using a trigger. Problem: The trigger always puts in the data on the first sheet, but my Evaluation list is the 6th sheet and called Evaluation.  What do I have to enter into the code so that the values are entered on the 6th sheet (evaluation)?

````
 var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var aktuellerZeitpunkt=new Date();
 var zeitStempelFormat="dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss";

 tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+1,56).setValue(aktuellerZeitpunkt).setNumberFormat(zeitStempelFormat);
 var checklist=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Phase 1-6 checklist");
 var currentValue1=checklist.getRange("BJ406").getValue();
 var currentValue2=checklist.getRange("BK406").getValue();
 var currentValue3=checklist.getRange("BL406").getValue();
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,57).setValue('=\'Phase 1-6 checklist\'!BH406');
   tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,58).setValue('1-6');
  tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,59).setValue('=\'Phase 1-6 checklist\'!BJ406').setValue(currentValue1);
 tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,60).setValue('=\'Phase 1-6 checklist\'!BK406').setValue(currentValue2);
 tabellenblatt.getRange(tabellenblatt.getLastRow()+0,61).setValue('=\'Phase 1-6 checklist\'!BL406').setValue(currentValue3);
}```
````

Comment: Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to read [ask] and then [edit] your question and add your code. Because it is impossible to help you with your code if we don't see what you did.

Comment: the code is pretty useless in this case I guess, but can you help me?

Comment: i posted the code in the question

Comment: You set here to use the active sheet `var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` If you want to use any other sheet you must set your other sheet there. • Your code is never useles, because it shows what you have done/tried so far.

Comment: so: ```var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(Evaluation);```   Like this? OR: ``` var tabellenblatt=SpreadsheetApp.Evaluation();``` Like This?

Comment: like this: [Get Sheet By Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867655/get-sheet-by-name)

Comment: TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname is not a function - that doesn't work :(

Comment: ok now it works, thank you, had to add .getActive() in between SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Sheet By Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867655/get-sheet-by-name)